# What does one mean by a 'transaction' in blockchain?

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, bitcoin, cryptocurrency

I mean, when I hear the word transaction the only thing that pops into my mind is a financial transaction. I don't quite get what a transaction means in the blockchain.
Does it always have to be a financial transaction to be recorded as a transaction?

Answer (score 0):

> Does it always have to be a financial transaction to be recorded as a transaction?

Depends upon the type of blockchain you are referring to. In the case of cryptocurrency, it is a financial transaction.

But in general, a transaction is a record of the exchange of data or assets among the participants in the network.

Comment: So, any exchange of information is recorded as a transaction. Okay! Thanks!

Comment: @Prab-mat no problem. Happy to help...  ^_^

Answer (score 0):

in blockchains every call to any function, every publication of contracts (codes) or whatever, has a fee, called "Gas Fee"

Consequently, every time a transaction is made, you pay, and therefore it is called a transaction

Comment: Then, why does every call to any function always have a Gas Fee? Shouldn't be free if you are making a project at home.

Comment: if you are making a project at home, or for test, you can use testnets, where you pay "virtual money", but if you use the main net of a blockchain, you have to pay 
Read this to know why: https://ethereum.org/en/developers/docs/gas/

Comment: Ohh.. thanks for the reference.

Comment: no problem, if it was helpful, mark it ;)

Answer (score 0):

Based on [Truffle Docs](https://www.trufflesuite.com/docs/truffle/getting-started/interacting-with-your-contracts), There are 2 important things to note in blockchain area :

1. Transactions
2. Calls

Transactions is a transaction can be as simple as sending Ether to another account, or as complicated as executing a contract function or adding a new contract to the network. It need cost ether to run (gas)

Calls can be used to execute code on the network, though no data will be permanently changed. Calls are free to run, and their defining characteristic is that they read data.

hope it answer your question